# NSLocalizedString with format

Tags: objective-c, nslocalizedstring

How would I use `NSLocalizedString` for this string:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Is “%@“ still correct for “%@“ tap “OK“ otherwise tap “Change“ to choose new contact details", individual.contactInfo, individual.name];
```

When using stringWithFormat before I've used it in the following manner:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", itemCount, NSLocalizedString(@"number of items", nil)];
```

Comment: Hot Licks has the right answer, but I'd also suggest reading http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/

Comment: I guess my answer doesn't handle the embedded quotes, but they were broken in the original.

Comment: One apparent short-coming of the iOS implementation for localized strings is that the comment is not included as a part of the key.  For this reason you can have two different messages with the same English wording but different comments, and the OS will not (apparently) be able to disambiguate them.

Comment: This is a [very good article](https://medium.com/@mendibarouk/enhance-your-localized-capabilities-on-your-ios-applications-d3ba17138077) about localization in Swift for a robust architecture

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Is “%@“ still correct for “%@“ tap “OK“ otherwise tap “Change“ to choose new contact details", @"Query if parm 1 is still correct for parm 2"), individual.contactInfo, individual.name];
```

Comment: Ah so NSLocalizedString recognizes `%@`?

Comment: No, but stringWithFormat does.

Comment: If you're on Swift, you can use `String(format: NSLocalizedString("foo %@ baz"), "bar")`.

Answer (score 34):

Given sentences can be constructed with the *variable parts* in a different order in some languages then I think you should use positional arguments with `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`:

```
NSString *format = NSLocalizedString(@"number_of_items", @"Number of items");
```

Which would load the following string for English:

```
@"Is \"%1$@\" still correct for \"%2$@\" tap \"OK\" otherwise tap \"Change\" to choose new contact details"
```

And perhaps something else for French (I don't know French so I won't attempt a translation, but it could well have the first and second argument in a different order):

```
"French \"%2$@\" french \"%1$@\" french"
```

And you can safely format the string as normal:

```
NSString *translated = [NSString stringWithFormat:format individual.contactInfo, individual.name];
```

Comment: You don't need to use position-specifying tokens in the English version (if the order conforms without).  They can still be used in the French (or whatever) if needed.

Comment: @HotLicks I think it makes sense to use them everywhere if used at all.

Answer (score 13):

I just want to add one very helpful definition which I use in many of my projects.

I've added this function to my `header prefix` file:

```
#define NSLocalizedFormatString(fmt, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(fmt, nil), __VA_ARGS__]
```

This allows you to define a localized string like the following:

```
 "ExampleScreenAuthorizationDescriptionLbl"= "I authorize the payment of %@ to %@.";
```

and it can be used via:

```
self.labelAuthorizationText.text = NSLocalizedFormatString(@"ExampleScreenAuthorizationDescriptionLbl", self.formattedAmount, self.companyQualifier);
```

Comment: Works like a charm and very elegant.

Comment: Note, though, that this kills the `genstrings` tool that only searches for direct references to NSLocalizedStrings. It does not process macros.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift**

> //Localizable.strings
>
> "my-localized-string" = "foo %@ baz";

Example:

```
myLabel.text = String(format: NSLocalizedString("my-localized-string", 
                                       comment: "foo %@ baz"), "bar") //foo bar baz
```