# How does localizedStringWithFormat work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nslocalizedstring, stringwithformat

**Please note**

I am not asking about `NSLocalizedString()` the macro. I am asking about the `NSString` class function `+ (instancetype)localizedStringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...`.

These are two separate things.

**Question**

I'm trying to use the `NSString` class method `localizedStringWithFormat` but I just can't work out how I'm supposed to use it.

Whatever I try I don't seem to get the words to appear in the translation file using Xcode 6 `export for localization`. I've tried the top two variations here but nothing.

The example in the docs shows...

```
NSString *myString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@:  %f", @"Cost", 1234.56];
```

Does this mean I have to separate the translated words from the numbers? i.e. could I not just use...

```
NSString *myString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"Cost:  %f", 1234.56];
```

If I can use this then what would the translated phrase be and what would the translation be?

If not then why use this at all? Why not just use...

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:  %f", NSLocalizedString(@"Cost"), 1234.56];
```

What is the difference with this last one?

Either way, can someone show me how to get the actual words translated in this please.

**Update**

OK, at the moment I'm using a stupid work around that just seems to be misusing everything lol.

If I do...

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:  %f", NSLocalizedString(@"Cost"), 1234.56];
```

Then it translated the word "Cost" but doesn't use the correct locale for the numbers.

If I use...

```
NSString *myString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@:  %f", @"Cost", 1234.56];
// or
NSString *myString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"Cost:  %f", 1234.56];
```

Then Xcode "Export for localization" just ignores it completely and nothing about "Cost" is added to the translation file at all so nothing gets translated.

So, I've resorted to using...

```
[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@:  %f", NSLocalizedString(@"Cost", @"Cost context stuff..."), 1234.56];
```

This adds "Cost" to the translation file and converts the number to the correct locale but seems like I'm using a lot of redundant stuff here.

Comment: @matt yeah, I've seen that. I just can't get the words to translate. I've tried everything I can think of but the words just don't seem to appear in the translation file. I get the translated number format and then english text.

Comment: @matt yes, we have translated into 15 languages and around 50 words per language. This is the only bit that isn't working. I've updated the question now.

Comment: @matt I'm not sure what these last two comments mean though? I know translation is up to me. I know locale is different from language. Neither of these facts help me get the text of this translated.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of the function.  Reread the spec.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984555/nslocalizedstring-with-format).

Comment: @HotLicks Hmm... but that question has no mention of the class function `[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:...]`. From the docs... **Returns a string created by using a given format string as a template into which the remaining argument values are substituted according to the current locale.** that seems to be what I'm using it for. Please could you explain which bit I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: You mistakenly believe that strings will be substituted.  What's "localized" is, eg, the use of `.` or `,` as a "decimal point".

Comment: @HotLicks ah! So the mention of **localized string** in both `NSLocalizedString` and `localizedStringWithFormat` is a complete red herring because they actually mean completely different things. Thank you, I finally get it now. Good thing they're not given names that make them look like they do the same thing. (Good joke Apple engineers, lol). Thank you, I get it now.

Comment: @HotLicks put it as an answer. I'll accept it. I think I need to keep this here for the next time I get "Localized String" confused with "Localized String" lol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update;** Addressing actual question as it evolved:

```
localizedStringWithFormat:
```

Will change how format specifiers are replaced.

From Apple's NSString docs:

> Discussion
>
> This method is equivalent to using initWithFormat:locale: and passing the current locale as the locale argument.

In other words, beside formatting, ensures the text is not re-translated (by somehow marking it as already translated).

### Original answer

When you think of NSLocalizedStrings - think key/value.  You can play some tricks with the key, like with your second example:

```
@"Cost:  %f"
```

That's a key - the value would probably be something that looks like @"SomeOtherWord: %f", - %f is still used a part of a format string afterwards.

The last example you gave:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:  %f", NSLocalizedString(@"Cost"), 1234.56];
```

Allows your separate out the translation of the word "Cost" with the reset of the string, which might be fine - but could be insufficient to effectively convey your meaning in all languages.  Maybe there's a language that you wouldn't Label:value, then just translating "Cost" doesn't get you to good localization.

NSLocalizedString can help with most of those situations, but localization is hard and filled with special cases, so your code might have special cases too - just try your best to keep those isolated from the rest of the logic.

Comment: That's what I first thought (that the text was the key). But when I use it nothing is added to the translation files to actually translate it. Is that a bug in Xcode's export for localization function maybe?

Comment: What happens if you do it in two stages?  First get the NSLocalizedString (key), then do a stringWithFormat:.  Does XCode populate things correctly?

Comment: Trying the commandline version: "xcodebuild -exportLocalizations" might have some useful output.  Or likely, it's a bug/missing feature on localizedStringWithFormat:

Comment: I found out from @HotLicks that `localizedStringWithFormat` doesn't translate at all. It localises number formats etc... Even though they have the same name `localizedString` they don't actually mean the same thing. I've used the method you suggested except using `localizedStringWithFormat...` and it all works now :D

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer to be more accurate.  The docs to the rescue!