# How to use NSLocalizedString function with variables in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nslocalizedstring, xliff

I'm trying to localize my app using `NSLocalizedString`. When I import the XLIFF file, most works like a charm but something do not and some string is not localized. I have noticed that the problem is from `NSLocalizedString` containing something variable inside like:

```
NSLocalizedString(" - \(count) Notifica", comment: "sottotitolo prescrizione per le notifiche al singolare")
```

or

```
NSLocalizedString("Notifica per \(medicina!) della prescrizione \(prescription!)\nMemo: \(memoTextView.text)", comment: "Messaggio della Local Notification")
```

Maybe this is not the correct syntax for this kind of stuff. Someone can explain me how to do that in Swift?

Comment: This is a [very good article](https://medium.com/@mendibarouk/enhance-your-localized-capabilities-on-your-ios-applications-d3ba17138077) about localization in Swift for a robust architecture

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use the `sprintf` format parameters within `NSLocalizedString`, so your example can look like this:

```
let myString = String(format: NSLocalizedString(" - %d Notifica", comment: "sottotitolo prescrizione per le notifiche al singolare"), count)
```

Comment: How does it look like in the Localizable.string

Comment: same as in Obj-C: `" - %d Notifica"=" - %d Notifica";`

Comment: How do i substitute a string? I tried to use `%s` modifier which didn't work =\

Comment: @igrek Use `%@` for substituting a string.

Comment: The reference for these formatting parameters is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Can you tell me the use of comment parameters inside  NSLocalizedString() ??

Answer (score 114):

In Session #412 of the WWDC2014 "Localizing with Xcode 6" the proper way to this in Swift is the following:

```
String.localizedStringWithFormat(
    NSLocalizedString(" - %d Notifica",
    comment: "sottotitolo prescrizione per le notifiche al singolare"),
    count)
```

> **Note** that `localizedStringWithFormat` sets the returned String's `local` based on given first argument:
>
> - No, it does not translate anything.
> - This confusion comes from wrong naming of `NSLocalizedString`.
> - It should have been named `NSTranslatedString`, or `NSTranslatable` (instead of `NSLocalizedString`).

Comment: Why do you need to use NSLocalizedString(...)? doesn't it happen in the implementation of String.localizedStringWithFormat(...)?

Comment: Check out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237549/how-does-localizedstringwithformat-work)

Comment: Thanks I already saw it after I asked. It will be very helpful for others so thanks

Answer (score 26):

I have followed the approach of creating  extension to String as i have many strings to localize.

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment:"")
    }
}
```

To use it for localization  in code do:

```
self.descriptionView.text = "Description".localized
```

For strings with dynamic variables follow :

```
self.entryTimeLabel.text = "\("Doors-open-at".localized) \(event.eventStartTime)"
```

Declare the strings in String files for different languages (example : Arabic and English)

[image]
[image]

Hope will be helping!

Comment: But it seems to me you're just attaching the time to the string.  What if your localised string was like `The doors open at %@ o'clock`.  Would your solution still work?

Comment: Yes, it is working perfectly as i'm getting time as String from back.

Comment: Thanks for including a reference to `Localizable.strings`. However, I think @Houman has a valid concern.

Comment: I don't know why people want to drop out "comment" value. It gives the description of the text and its purpose to localisation engineers without which they cannot make out the intention to use that text on a button or as a label etc.

Comment: This is not ok as Houman said, but it's a generic way of concatenate strings.

Comment: This is not a good idea, because it assumes that the "doors open at" text will precede the time value in every language, but this is not necessarily true. It's better to use `localizedStringWithFormat` so that you can vary the position of the interpolated value if needed.

Comment: this answer is totally incorrect! In some languages you may have a different substring order to insert bad you hardcode the order

Answer (score 17):

Here is an extension I use in String, it adds a localizeWithFormat function with variable arguments,

```
extension String {

     func localizeWithFormat(arguments: CVarArg...) -> String{
        return String(format: self.localized, arguments: arguments)        
     }
            
     var localized: String{
         return Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: self, value: nil, table: "StandardLocalizations")
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
let siriCalendarText = "AnyCalendar"
let localizedText = "LTo use Siri with my app, please set %@ as the default list on your device reminders settings".localizeWithFormat(arguments: siriCalendarTitle)
```

Just be careful not to use the same function and property names that String has. I normally use a 3 letter prefix for all my framework functions.

Answer (score 16):

I tried the above solutions however the code below worked for me

**SWIFT 4**

```
extension String {

    /// Fetches a localized String
    ///
    /// - Returns: return value(String) for key
    public func localized() -> String {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "en", ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        return (bundle?.localizedString(forKey: self, value: nil, table: nil))!
    }


    /// Fetches a localised String Arguments
    ///
    /// - Parameter arguments: parameters to be added in a string
    /// - Returns: localized string
    public func localized(with arguments: [CVarArg]) -> String {
        return String(format: self.localized(), locale: nil, arguments: arguments)
    }

}

// variable in a class
 let tcAndPPMessage = "By_signing_up_or_logging_in,_you_agree_to_our"
                                     .localized(with: [tAndc, pp, signin])

// Localization File String
"By_signing_up_or_logging_in,_you_agree_to_our" = "By signing up or logging in, you agree to our \"%@\" and \"%@\" \nAlready have an Account? \"%@\"";
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the same functions for `UILabel`

```
extension UILabel {
    
    func setLocalizedText(key: String) {
        self.text = key.localized
    }
    
    func setLocalizedText(key: String, arguments: [CVarArg]) {
        self.text = String(format: key.localized, arguments: arguments)
    }
}
```

If you want you can move this `localized` property to UILabel as well

```
extension String {
        
    var localized: String{
        return Bundle.main.localizedString(forKey: self, value: nil, table: nil)
    }
}
```

My localizable

```
"hi_n" = "Hi, %@!";
```

Used them like this:

```
self.greetingLabel.setLocalizedText(key: "hi_n", arguments: [self.viewModel.account!.firstName])
// Shows this on the screen -> Hi, StackOverflow!
```

Comment: How does swift know which "setLocalizedText" to pick since in your string extension, there are 2?

Comment: @RobertBrax it will know by the number of arguments you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a custom global function instead of an extension, because `genstrings` is just parsing the source code for `NSLocalizedString` with literals. That means you wont be able to automatically generate the `.strings` files from your source coder with the extension solutions.

```
func NSLocalizedString(_ key: String, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main, value: String = "", comment: String, with arguments: CVarArg...) -> String {
    let localizedString = Foundation.NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: tableName, bundle: bundle, value: value, comment: comment)
    return String.localizedStringWithFormat(localizedString, arguments)
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I created an `extension` to `String` since I had many `strings` to be `localized`.

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

For example:

```
let myValue = 10
let anotherValue = "another value"

let localizedStr = "This string is localized: \(myValue) \(anotherValue)".localized
print(localizedStr)
```

Comment: The big downside to this approach is that you have to manually extract the strings to send to the translator as `Editor > Export for Localization...` won't pick them up.

Comment: Given what @JasonMoore suggested, I don't think this is the right approach.

Comment: @JasonMoore totally agree with you. Did any of you guys find a solution for this?

Comment: i don't knew why this solution is downrated :( .  and almost the below  nest below solution is the same but it have uprate