# NSLocalizedString With Dynamic Variable (Swift) - Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

I began integrating localization into my app using [this guide](http://rshankar.com/internationalization-and-localization-of-apps-in-xcode-6-and-swift/). It worked great until I localized a string that included a dynamic variable. The original was this:

```
let myString = "I have \(countOfMoney) dollars in my wallet."
```

Then I tried to mimiic [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277626/nslocalizedstring-with-swift-variable) stack answer to localize it. However, I'm getting an EXC_Bad_Access error. Below is how I tried to localize it.

This is in my Localizable.strings English file:

```
localizedMsg="I have %@ dollars in my wallet.";
```

This is in my View Controller:

```
let countOfMoney = moneyInWallet.count
let localizedMsg = String(format: NSLocalizedString("localizedMsg", comment: ""), countOfMoney)
```

However, this line shows up as an error when I run the app on the simulator. How do I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSLocalizedString with swift variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277626/nslocalizedstring-with-swift-variable)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your setup isn't correct. Your code should look like this:

```
let localizedMsg = String(format: NSLocalizedString("I have %d dollars in my wallet.", comment: ""), countOfMoney)
```

Now run `genstrings` to get your updated Localizable.strings file.

That will add the line:

```
"I have %d dollars in my wallet." = "I have %d dollars in my wallet.";
```

Also note the change from `%@` to `%d`. This assumes that `countOfMoney` is an integer type. Only use `%@` for object pointers.

Comment: I just mimicked the form of your code and it worked, so thank you. What did you mean by run genstrings though?

Comment: `genstrings` is the tool that scans all of your source code for calls to `NSLocalizedString` and generates the `Localizable.strings` file for you.