# Localizable strings shows key instead of value every other time

Tags: ios, swift, enums, localizable.strings

I have a weird inconsistency with my `localizable` `strings` where sometimes the `value` is shown and sometimes thee `key` is shown. It's about every other time I restart the app. I use a lot of `localizable` `strings` in the project and they all work fine except for the ones I use in conjunction with this `enum`, which of course makes me think there is something wrong with it:

```
enum ParameterDescription  {
    
    case parameterDescription(id: Int)
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .parameterDescription(let id):
            return "parameterDescription_\(id)"
        }
    }
}
```

This returns the `string` I expect, like `parameterDescription_0` or `parameterDescription_3`. And then I hook on `localized`:

```
print(ParameterDescription.parameterDescription(id: 0).description.localized())

extension String {
    func localized() -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}
```

And sometimes I get the correct associated value, but if I build and run the code again without changing anything, I (might) get the `key` printed as a `string` instead, which I guess means that `Xcode` couldn't find the `string`.

Is there something wrong with the `enum` or some reason it can't be used like this? Or is it something else? I have checked through the project folders so that there aren't any conflicting files, and as I previously said, I only experience this problem using this `enum` and/or this `key`. And there are thousands of `localized` `strings` in the project.

I have checked similar threads, but there doesn't seem to be any answer that is relevant for this.

Comment: Have you checked whether you have values for those `key`s in all `.lproj` files?

Comment: I would check the localized strings for typos or for missing `;` at the end of lines. Also check that every case is covered (since the `id` can be an arbitrary number). And/or you could change your logic and have localizable parameters, like in https://stackoverflow.com/q/26277626/2227743