# NSLocalized Creating a varying string from strings file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nslocalizedstring

I have a string which hold a varying part in the middle according to some cases.

Example: You lost ***255*** points.

The point value "255" is the varying part and I want to hold the non-varying part in my string file. However I don't want to have two entries in my strings file like.

"string_start" = "You lost"
"string_end" = "points."

Btw the points part which is (255) in the example is an NSMutableAttributedString to support a different color and font style.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984555/nslocalizedstring-with-format

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"You lost %d points", nil), 255]
```

and you localize `@"You lost %d points"` in whatever language you want.

Comment: I know I didnt mention but If the %d part (point part) is an NSAttributedString with different font and color. Do you know how to format the string ?